Authentication prompt for "Connect to server" - Touch ID?
Is there any way to make the 'Connect to server' routine in Finder authenticate in a different way?
As a basic password prompt, it's a bit annoying to have to find the password and paste it in. But I don't want to save the password, as then there's no security at all once I'm logged in.
Is there any way at all to connect to a Samba share but make authentication via Touch ID? A little like the way you can set sudo to use Touch ID, or use Secretive to do ssh login keys behind a Touch ID prompt. Can a samba share be added with Touch ID control?
Otherwise, it feels either too slow or too insecure.
